# Unable to load libgdiplus in Signal R web application with web sockets (Mac OS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, signalr, system.drawing

I downloaded [this repository](https://github.com/ardacetinkaya/WebCam-Streaming) from GitHub and try to run it on my MacOS laptop. It uses Signal R and web sockets.
It builds, it starts, it works

But when I try to open web socket I get an error:

```bash
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.
       ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libgdiplus' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(liblibgdiplus, 0x0001): tried: 'liblibgdiplus' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSliblibgdiplus' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblibgdiplus' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'liblibgdiplus' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/liblibgdiplus' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblibgdiplus' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
         at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdiplusStartup(IntPtr& token, StartupInput& input, StartupOutput& output)
         at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip..cctor()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I did `brew install mono-libgdiplus` but it didn't help.

I'm new to C# and Microsoft frameworks so what else can I do? (MacOS Ventura, Apple M1)

Solved: `System.Drawing` is not supported on my MacOS, so the peaces of code where this library is using should not be executed.

Comment: Error says gdip is not found.  gdip is library for Autohotkey supporting objects.  See following : https://github.com/topics/gdip

Comment: While you are new, you hit hard on `System.Drawing` that should be used no more on non-Windows platform. Please switch to alternative libraries on drawing something.

Comment: @LexLi I found a peace of code where `System.Drawing` was used and commented it. Now everything works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the project you played with was very well designed for cross platform, it was unfortunately developed before .NET 6 introduced [an important breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only), that `System.Drawing` related API is only supported on Windows.

Like you found out, commenting out the lines related to `System.Drawing` works. But if you want similar functionalities, you will have to rewrite that part with another drawing library. There are many such options out there if search engines are used.